# How can rows between nulls be extracted using Python or Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a csv fie (or a bunch of CSV files) with the following data..

```
          Datetime 89200000 89300000  ...  106200000  106300000 107900000
0                   NaN      NaN     C202  ...       C3A4        NaN      C09C
1                   NaN      NaN   BBC R2  ...      Heart        NaN    Sangam
2  2019-09-09T00:05:00Z      NaN       72  ...         64        NaN        37
3  2019-09-09T00:11:00Z      NaN       72  ...         64        NaN        36
4  2019-09-09T00:17:00Z      NaN       72  ...         64        NaN        36
5                   NaN      NaN     C202  ...       C3A4        NaN      C09C
6                   NaN      NaN   BBC R2  ...      Heart        NaN    Sangam
7  2019-09-09T00:23:00Z      NaN       72  ...         64        NaN        36
8                   NaN      NaN     C202  ...       C3A4        NaN      C09C
9                   NaN      NaN   BBC R2  ...      Heart        NaN    Sangam
```

I need to extract rows such that I end up with the following -

```
Datetime 89200000 89300000  ...  106200000  106300000 107900000
0                   NaN      NaN     C202  ...       C3A4        NaN      C09C
1                   NaN      NaN   BBC R2  ...      Heart        NaN    Sangam
2  2019-09-09T00:05:00Z      NaN       72  ...         64        NaN        37
3  2019-09-09T00:11:00Z      NaN       72  ...         64        NaN        36
4  2019-09-09T00:17:00Z      NaN       72  ...         64        NaN        36
```

followed by ...

```
Datetime 89200000 89300000  ...  106200000  106300000 107900000
5                   NaN      NaN     C202  ...       C3A4        NaN      C09C
6                   NaN      NaN   BBC R2  ...      Heart        NaN    Sangam
7  2019-09-09T00:23:00Z      NaN       72  ...         64        NaN        36
8                   NaN      NaN     C202  ...       C3A4        NaN      C09C
9                   NaN      NaN   BBC R2  ...      Heart        NaN    Sangam
```

and so on for all rows in the file.

I am happy with either a pythonic approach or pandas and have looked at various examples posted however couldn't solve this puzzle so far. Please help and let me know if you need more information.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Series.isna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html) + [`Series.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) + [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) 
to create groups based on the mentioned criteria. Then you can get them and save them in a list using [`get_group`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.get_group.html):

```
groups=df['Datetime'].isna().cumsum()
grouper=df.groupby(groups)
dfs=[grouper.get_group(g) for g in groups]
```

**this will create a list of DataFrame that will be the ones you are looking for.**

If you specify where you want to save the resulting dataframes I will be happy to modify my answer to help you.

Note: I think you want to distinguish based on the NaN of the Datetime column. If you want to do it based on another column just change this label

Comment: Thanks - just tried your solution out. It works with a slight modification as below

groups=(df['Datetime'].isna() & df['Datetime'].shift().notna()).cumsum()
grouper=df.groupby(groups)
dfs=[g for _, g in grouper]

I borrowed the last line from the solution provided by @Valdi_Bo below, otherwise the result isnt what is required.

Thanks for this..

Answer (score 1):

As I understood, you want to convert your DataFrame into a **list** of
DataFrames (segments of the original DataFrame).

Each "segment" should end at the end of a sequence of "not-*NaT*" values
and the following sequence of *NaT* values should be the start of the
next "segment".

To provide such "cutting", group your DataFrame as follows:

```
gr = df.groupby((df['Datetime'].isna() & df['Datetime']\
    .shift().notna()).cumsum())
```

Then generate your list as:

```
dfs = [ grp for _, grp in gr ]
```

So my solution cuts your DataFrame into **three** segments (key ==
[0..4], [5..7] and [8..9]), whereas the other solution cuts it into
**ten** segments (something must be wrong there).

Comment: Thanks! It works and does the job in about 6 seconds ...which is good! :)